# How long should a MySQL connection take to create?

Tags: mysql

I've got some code connecting to a MySQL database and running a simple query. I have instrumented everything and my timer is showing that the first query returns after 12 milliseconds. The code does this:

```
make database connection -> run query -> parse results -> return results
```

Maybe I'm insane but 12 milliseconds feels like an eternity in the world of computing. Is this the standard amount of time it takes to connect to and run a query on a vanilla install of MySQL?

If not, I need to reevaluate the library I am using to make connections to MySQL.

Comment: What was the query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM user -> returns 4 results of just id,username

Comment: That doesn't seem too far off, especially if you're running this on your desktop or something.

Comment: 12ms doesn't sound so long, but if that's a problem for you, try persistent connections.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider what goes into constructing and destroying a MySQL DB Connection

Please read my post [***How costly is opening and closing of a DB connection?***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16973/877) in the DBA StackExchange. It will explain what buffers are created for each session.

If 12ms seems like eternity to do this, [**go with the suggestion to do persistent connections**](https://serverfault.com/questions/642582/how-long-should-a-mysql-connection-take-to-create#comment775624_642582). Personally, I shy away from persistent connections. Perhaps setting smaller values for session buffers may help a little.